# How to implement IEnumerable<T> with GetEnumerator()?

Tags: c#, ienumerable

I would like my type to implement `IEnumerable<string>` . I tried to follow C# in a Nutshell, but something went wrong:

```
public class Simulation : IEnumerable<string>
{
    private IEnumerable<string> Events()
    {
        yield return "a";
        yield return "b";
    }

    public IEnumerator<string> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return Events().GetEnumerator();
    }
}
```

But I get the build error

> Error 1   'EventSimulator.Simulation' does not implement interface member 'System.Collections.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()'. 'EventSimulator.Simulation.GetEnumerator()' cannot implement 'System.Collections.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()' because it does not have the matching return type of 'System.Collections.IEnumerator'.

Comment: Aside: you can `yield return` directly from inside `GetEnumerator()`

Answer (score 43, accepted):

You're missing `IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()`:

```
public class Simulation : IEnumerable<string>
{
    private IEnumerable<string> Events()
    {
        yield return "a";
        yield return "b";
    }

    public IEnumerator<string> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return Events().GetEnumerator();
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return GetEnumerator();
    }
}
```

Comment: Had a question, but @NominSim answered it in the post below - nevermind!

Comment: thanks, now I can add this to my EF TT file ;-)

Comment: FYI, let Visual Studio type this out for you.  When you type `public class Simulation : IEnumerable<string>`, right-click on the `IEnumerable` part and go Implement Interface > Implement Interface.  Visual Studio will fill in the parts of the interface that you haven't already filled in.

Answer (score 8):

IEnumerable requires that you implement both the typed and generic method.

In the community section of the msdn [docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9eekhta0.aspx) it explains why you need both. (For backwards compatibility is the reason given essentially).